# Which shields have damaging parries?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I was doing some research on shields, trying to understand "Parry Power" and I came upon this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/5z8z7b/botw_what_the_shield_ratings_actually_mean/). A part of it reads:

> **For starters, the vast majority of shields don't register the parry as an attack**--it will simply go through the enemy without damaging them. Perfect guarding melee attacks doesn't do damage either. Furthermore, shields that do have damaging parries inflict much less damage than their "power" rating suggests.

Now I'm wondering exactly what shields *do* register a parry as an attack. Why would one shield be considered capable of dealing damage while another one would not?

I think there may be some hints in the shield descriptions, such as this one:

> This Lizal shield has been strengthened by adding a different type of metal to the mix. **The edge is lined with spikes, so handle with care**.

[image: https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/zelda.gamepedia.com/4/4a/BotW_Reinforced_Lizal_Shield_Icon.png?version=7ca376a32cd470258871261a25714a08]

Maybe the "spiked" varients of shields can do offensive parries. **I'm looking for a list of exactly which shields can be used to perform a damaging parry.**

Comment: Good Question, ill try to find an answer

Comment: huh, TIL some shields damage. Just goes to show how much stuff is packed into this game. Good Question.

Comment: I wish a shield's numerical value represented its durability. It feels arbitrary to sort them based on parry power when it turns out only three shields actually do damage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://orcz.com/Breath_of_the_Wild:_Shields_List), the [Lynel Shield](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Lynel_Shield), [Savage Lynel Shield](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Savage_Lynel_Shield), and [Mighty Lynel Shield](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Mighty_Lynel_Shield) are the shields that deal damage when a parry is performed

> **Parry Power** As described in the Nintendo Guide, this is the damage you do when you perform a parry action. Only certain spiked shields like the Lynel Shield will damage the enemy when you parry.

The reason why these shields are able to deal damage is due the blades that are attached to the shield. From the Lynel Shield wikis

> The shield's blades grant this shield the ability to cut when the shield is used to parry (which is normally used to initiate a Perfect Guard). Link can even cut grass by parrying with this shield in grassy areas (doing this will not reduce the shield's durability).

Answer (score 3):

According to my own experience as well as [this link](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/18970-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75112999), the only shield that does damage when using the parry "attack" is a Lynel shield. Typically most players try to avoid doing this, since the attack is extremely close range, slow, and leaves you open and vulnerable for an excessive amount of time.

Comment: Unless you're trying to defeat Calamity Ganon shield-only (or any given boss for that matter). Not a big surprise that some people would do that, given the amount of challenges those madfolk come up with.